# Could someone bring Google OAuth2 for Cloud DNS via Rest to light?

Tags: c#, api, rest, google-app-engine, dns

Infinite Loop Error.

I have been spending way too much time going in circles in Googles really terrible API documentation regarding implementation of their cloud services in a desktop application.

First major problem, it seems that I must use Oauth2 somehow in order to obtain additional client credentials (which I must update/refresh using a refresh token as this changes as well) -- since apparently the API credentials just aren't enough to do full on communication.

https://cloud.google.com/dns/api/authorization

Could someone give an example using C# .NET in a WinForms application that uses rest or the Google .NET API library to establish the required OAuth2 token data/etc which will then later be used to access all of these API's here.

https://cloud.google.com/dns/api/v1/managedZones

And please ---- no gcloud.exe stuff. Not practical to expect clients to download that massive and over complicated installer just to get the tool.  :)

Comment: Would you mind describing what your app is actually doing? Depending on you use case you might want to use a service account - which are relatively easy to use. I'd also recommend posting what you've done so far if you want help from the community.

Comment: @konqi - Thank you for your reply.  The application will be responsible for adding domains (register/create), and adding/updating the DNS records.  Users should also be able to delete their domains or delete records, and list the dns servers that the need to use for example:  `ns1.google.ca`, `ns2.google.ca` --- the DNS servers that google set up for the records which the user must apply to their domain at (for example) GoDaddy or whoever they bought the domain through.

Comment: So will users use their own account to access Cloud DNS or will this be a provided service (you will host dns for them in your account)? My questions aims primarily to understand who/what will be authenticated. In the first use case you're basically creating a UI for CloudDNS settings. In the latter case you'd be a service provider.

Comment: @konqi - No problem clarifying.  I know that ACL is pretty important for the direction of communication.    Users will be responsible for creating an app in their own google accounts, which means they have full control and responsibility over their own domains / dns.  I am not intending to be a service provider.

Comment: Okay, i haven't done this in a while with C# but if you post your code related to oauth2 authentication I might be able to hint you in the right direction.

Comment: Thats pretty much my problem.  Can't make heads or tails out of googles docs on their Oauth2 calls, nor what all is required to do so.  I could re-open all the links again, but it's like a bad nightmare -- insanity starts to kick in after 30-40 tabs are open in the same site.

Comment: right, so here is some literature i recommend reading in order: how oauth2 works for installed applications:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp

simple example to start with
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started

sample implementations:
https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples

Comment: I think there is some miscommunication.  I have been through the docs on googles site.  Event played around in their sandbox,   have the libs downloaded and was trying to fudge with them randomly, but at the same time knowing absolutely nothing will work until I get Oauth2 working -  problem is the Oauth2 needs to auth in the app --- eg ... forcing the user to put a web script up somewhere just so it can receive a code on a get request from the oauth server is just bad design overall for a desktop application.  That being said, what parameters are required with what values is murky water

Comment: I have `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=123456789012.apps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=token&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/ndev.clouddns.readwrite&redirect_uri=https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/oauthWindow.html` which is as close as I can get to a functional Oauth2 url, and havn't even gotten into the DNS api's since they only have examples on how to call the books api's inside .NET.    ( https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/dns/v1/ - is where i got the above URL by toggling authorize with my popup blocker on so I can cap it b4 redirect)

Comment: Actually it's not and your insistence that the documentations suck doesn't help (mainly because i already knew that). First: yes, the user will have to interact with google in order to authenticate your app - there is no way around that with oauth. If you find one you broke it. What happens when the user is logged in and you app is authorized depends on what you provide as redirect_url. You can have google send the information to your app, or have the user copy the auth code into your app. Once that is done you can request a refresh token from google.

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp, search for urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob and urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto as redirect_url. There really is no need for an external web page when you use those.

Comment: @konqi - I get it.  Authorization is one thing, but being forced to handle receiving of the token via a URL instead of directly in app, is a nuisance.  That being said, my adherance to the lack of quality in the documentation is through my experience as a reader of thousands of API's over the years, as well as an author. The docs are unclear more specifically when dealing with using .NET.  I do appreciate your assistance, however if they were clear, we wouldn't be having this conversation in the first place ;)

Comment: I did try to do some digging on those, and also found somewhere buried in random segments of googles docs to set it to `http://localhost`, or something, but that would require a port open etc etc....

Comment: Well you could handle that in your app as well. Just provide a localhost-something as redirect_url and the use will be forwarded. Of course you'll have to open a tcp connection on that port and wait for the redirect, but you could then easily capture the information provided in the redirect url.

Comment: :-) That is true. But that's kind of by design. You have these three options: 1) Scan your windows for the correct title and take the auth code from the corresponding window. 2) open a port locally (even if just temporarily) 3) let the user copy the code. (He'll only have to do it once)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80378/discussion-between-sanuel-jackson-and-konqi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found some time to create a small sample application. You can find the code on [github](https://github.com/konqi/stackoverflow/tree/master/CloudDNSOAuthSample) .

You said you don't want to use the client_secrets.json. The only quick solution i found was to provide the necessary stuff via memory stream - there may be better ways.

Most of the authentication and Cloud DNS client is done in these lines

```
using (var memstream = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Ugly way of providing clientId & Secret inmemory
    var writer = new StreamWriter(memstream);
    writer.Write(@"{""installed"":{""auth_uri"":""https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"",""client_secret"":""");
    writer.Write(clientSecret);
    writer.Write(@""",""token_uri"":""https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"",""client_email"":"""",""redirect_uris"":[""urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"",""oob""],""client_x509_cert_url"":"""",""client_id"":""");
    writer.Write(clientId);
    writer.Write(@""",""auth_provider_x509_cert_url"":""https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs""}}");
    writer.Flush();
    memstream.Position = 0;

    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(memstream).Secrets,
        new[] { DnsService.Scope.NdevClouddnsReadwrite},
        "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Books.ListMyLibrary"));
}

// Create the service.
var service = new DnsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "Cloud DNS API Sample",
    });
```

The example lacks any good coding style (I could use a  Json lib, and i could wrap the writer in using) but the sample should work.
I hope this helps in getting you on the right track.

Edit: I deleted the client id and secret used in the sample, so you need to replace those with your own to make the code work.

Comment: I managed to write the Oauth2 routine using the webbrowser control (to prompt for permissions), and I get back the token and process it.  Started just calling the rest api's directly.  I accepted your solution as you put forth a lot of effort towards this, and I may review again in the future if I need to use the Google .NET library.  Not sure why, but I find the browser control method is much simpler for getting the token.  Not sure what the `refresh` token and such are for, since, if using the token i get an error, I can always show the Oauth2 permission request window in a dialog again.

Comment: You still have the client_id, and secret inside the GitHub.  I suggest to change those or remove the access from your account so that people don't grab it and abuse your account.

Comment: I'm glad if you got it working. The client secret is not an issue as i removed the entire credential from my project.

Comment: Havn't made any rest requests to the dns api yet, but the permission flags are set, so I believe it should be ok. Just curious, I only need to use the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/ndev.clouddns.readwrite` in order to create/delete domains, as well as their records, or is there another permission i need above that -- say -- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` (although this scope seems a bit too wide).  I want to keep the scope as narrow as possible.

Comment: the former should be enough. I'd be reluctant to give such a wide scoped permission on my paid services.

Comment: After some testing, it appears it's not enough -.-.  Need  /cloud-platform as well in order to create new domains .  Appreciate all the assistance, and patience you have given with this.

Comment: well it should be enough for the cloud dns stuff. I'm not exactly sure how you add new domains for cloud dns. Everywhere else that happens with the old webmaster tools domain verification. That would be a different scope. When you search for the command you use to create new domains you should find the appropriate scope in the documentation. If not for much else, the docs work for that purpose quite well.

Comment: Thats where I got it from, was hoping I didn't need both scopes, but I do, unless there is something undocumented for a different scope that is more restrictive.  >https://cloud.google.com/dns/api/v1beta1/managedZones/create < will have to hit the google forums on that issue I guess and pray someone competant can give me a more restricted scope to accomplish the same thing.  I too am uncomfortable with requesting more permission than is necessary, and `cloud-platform` is enormous.

Comment: Well it seems both scopes are required. On a sidenote: I wouldn't use beta APIs. Google has a habit of changing stuff (at times radically) in beta products.